# How to run "make install" from Xcode

Tags: xcode, makefile

I have custom Makefile and External build target in Xcode.
When I click "Build" it runs "make"
When I click "Clear" it runs "make clean"

How to run "make install" (or any other target) from Xcode?

(btw, this is AVR project and xcode project file was created using avr-project tool shipped with Crosspack-AVR)

Answer (score 5):

```
$xcodebuild install
```

from the command line within the project directory, just like make.

Comment: Well, I mean "where to click in xcode" to run "make install" without using shell

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new external target and call make install or xcodebuild install